# Extract specific word 'A' only than when that word is mentioned more than 10 times(from first and last name)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to get from first name and last name how many times is mentioned the word " A" with the condition that is has to be mention more than 10 times. 
For example : 1. Alessandra Antatarovich Alatatatovica  2. Aaron Aaaantonich Albachiara .....

Expected result is :

```
                    `First_name             Last_name            Count`

                     Alessandra Antatarovich Alatatatovica        11
                     Aaron     Aaaantonich   Albachiaraaa         12
                     AAAAcc                 ABCDAAAAAAAAA         14
```

Name of the table is Client

If there is a name and last name with only 8 " A" than that record will not display.. If there is a record for example First name : AAABBBAAANHDHD and Last name : BBAAAAAAATK that has 13 " A" than this record will appear

Comment: @artm, from that example I did't risolve my problem.. I would appreciate if anyone could risolve my problem.. tnx

Comment: Can you please post some sample data, the expected result and what you already tried?

Comment: @ALEKSEJ, I wanted to use lenght, but i don't have idea how to get just "A" and than count how many times is displayed

Comment: @artm, this is not duplicated question. This query have to extract all records that contains more than 10 "A" and than display how many time is showed character "A "

Comment: I voted to re-open because there is a better answer than the accepted answer on the "duplicate".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle has the `regexp_count()` function for this purpose.

The basic syntax is:

```
select regexp_count(FirstName || LastName, 'A')
```

For the condition of 10, then something like:

```
select c.*, regexp_count(FirstName || LastName, 'A')
from client c
where  regexp_count(FirstName || LastName, 'A') > 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

and if no rexexp_count() in your SQL - you can use this simple trick:

```
select *, 
length(concat(First_name,Last_name))- length(substitue(concat(First_name,Last_name),'A','') as 'Acount'
from tableName
having Acount>10
```